# fetching the IDs of windows

Tags: jquery

I am Using jquery [windows engine plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqWindowsEngine). Im creating windows as following:

```
for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
    mywidth=i-1;
    mywidth = mywidth*newWidth;
    $.newWindow({
        id:"iframewindow"+i,
        posx:11+mywidth,
        posy:38,
        width:newWidth,
        height:maxHeight,
        title:"Window:"+i, 
        type:"iframe",
        onWindowClose:function(){
                    alert(id)
                }
                minimizeButton: true,
                        maximizeButton: true,
                        closeButton: true,
                        draggable: true,
                        resizeable: true
    });
    }
```

How can I fetch the id of a particular window in the onclose event.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 onWindowClose:function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this plugin, but a wild guess is `$(this).id` inside the onWindowClose handler.